# Use explicit execution context with OptionT[Future, _]

Tags: scala, scala-cats, monad-transformers

I am trying to write a custom [Akka SnapshotStore plugin](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/persistence-journals.html#snapshot-store-plugin-api).

I am at the point where I want to implement this method:

```scala
def loadAsync(persistenceId: String, criteria: SnapshotSelectionCriteria): Future[Option[SelectedSnapshot]]
```

This is what I have so far:

```scala
import cats.data.OptionT
import cats.implicits._
...  

override def loadAsync(
    persistenceId: String,
    criteria: SnapshotSelectionCriteria
  ): Future[Option[SelectedSnapshot]] = {
    // same as in the original plugin
    val metadata = snapshotMetadatas(persistenceId, criteria).sorted.takeRight(maxLoadAttempts)
    // need to get rid of this one! 
    import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

    val getSnapshotAndReportMetric = for {
      snapshot <- OptionT.fromOption[Future](getMaybeSnapshotFromMetadata(metadata))
      _ <- OptionT.liftF(Future {
        observabilityService
          .recordMetric(
            LongCounterMetric(readVehicleSnapshotFromDiskCounter, SnapShotDirectoryScannerCommandOptions)
          )
      }(directorySnapshotScanningDispatcher))
    } yield snapshot

    getSnapshotAndReportMetric.value.recoverWith {
      // retry if we listed an older snapshot that was deleted before loading
      case _: NoSuchFileException => loadAsync(persistenceId, criteria)
    }(streamDispatcher)
  }
```

For reference here is the signature of `getMaybeSnapshotFromMetadata`. It's signature can be modified to add a `Future`, but ultimately the wrapped response must be of type `Option[SelectedSnapshot]`.

```scala
private def getMaybeSnapshotFromMetadata(metadata: Seq[SnapshotMetadata]): Option[SelectedSnapshot]
```

The code as is compiles, but only because I have imported the implicit global `ExecutionContext`. My goal is to use different *explicit* execution contexts (different configurable dispatchers), but I don't see how to do it for the first line (the one that calls `getMaybeSnapshotFromMetadata`) within for-comprehensions. If I used `OptionT.liftF` then I could do it, e.g.

```scala
...
snapshot <- OptionT.liftF( Future { getMaybeSnapshotFromMetadata(metadata)}(streamDispatcher))
```

...but then I get a `OptionT[Future, Option[SelectedSnapshot]` as a result.

Is there a solution to what I want to achieve? If not I can work around with mere `Future`s and it's `andThen` chain method:

```scala
    Future {
      getMaybeSnapshotFromMetadata(metadata)
    }(streamDispatcher)
      .andThen(selectedSnapshot => {
        observabilityService
          .recordMetric(
            LongCounterMetric(readVehicleSnapshotFromDiskCounter, SnapShotDirectoryScannerCommandOptions)
          )
        selectedSnapshot
      })(opentelemetryDispatcher)
      .recoverWith {
        // retry if we listed an older snapshot that was deleted before loading
        case _: NoSuchFileException => loadAsync(persistenceId, criteria)
      }(streamDispatcher)
```

**Update** For the second line within for-comprehension `liftF` is actually a viable solution - I updated the code block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not overuse cats. It's a nice tool for some things, but when used improperly, it just adds complexity and hurts readability without any benefit.

```
    Future(getMaybeSnapshotFromMetadata(metadata))(streamDispatcher)
      .andThen { case _ => 
        observabilityService.recordWiseMetric(...)
      }(directorySnapshotScanningDispatcher) 
      .recoverWith(...)(streamDispatcher)
```

This is equivalent to your code without all the complication ...
It is *not* a "workaround", but an actual *proper* way to write this.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Dima    You're right. Please note that `onComplete` returns `Unit` and I need to eventually return output of `getMaybeSnapshotFromMetadata ` so I will go with the `andThen` instead (added it to the question).

Comment: ah, yeah, `andThen` is what's appropriate in this case. I'll update.

Comment: Np, I was glad to hear from you. You are missed 

Comment: @vasigorc "missed" from where? Do I know you? :)